# All quadrilaterals have their diagonals bisecting each other?

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles, bisection

As in the following figure of a quadrilateral;
[image]

If the diagonals are stated to bisect each other, I thought this should hold (considering the bottommost triangle in blue lines); $$\frac{\vec a+\vec b}{2}+\frac{\vec b-\vec a}{2}=\vec b$$

But this shows that all quadrilaterals have their diagonals bisecting each other, since this gives $\vec b = \vec b$, which implies it's true for all $\vec a $ and $\vec b$. Which obviously isn't true.

Where did my reasoning go wrong?,

Comment: I'm not so sure about your drawing, assuming a,b are supported by the two sides originating from o, then the long diagonal is not necessarily a+b as you stated. Also the formula you wrote is a tautology, so it does not help. What are you trying to achieve ? Find some vector characterization that diagonals are bisecting ? I think it would be better to have $4$ points $A,B,C,D$ and express things with vectors like $\vec{AB}$ and such.

Comment: What you said first fixes it- the vector to the upper-right end isn't $\vec a+ \vec b$. I messed up there and saw the nonsense result, so I wanted to know where I went wrong, that's all.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4063821/21813).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper right point is not $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ in general, if it is then we have a parallelogram, of which the diagonals bisect each other as you have proven.