# How is it the possible to find the ratio of the sides in the picture

Tags: vector-spaces, triangles, ratio

I am trying to calculate the ratio of CE(green) to BE(blue). Given that FC:FM = 3:1 and it's an equlateral triangle.

[image]

I have tried drawing triangles to get an approximation, and I have drawn it in the 3d plane to calculate it but I don't know how to calculate the AE or EF in that matter.
How would you go about it? Please just give me a hint not a solution.

Comment: Write vectors $\vec{AM}$, then CM, then CF, then AF and CB in the form $k\vec{AB}+l\vec{AC}$. Then write $\vec{AE} =x \vec{AF}=\vec{AC}+y\vec{CB}$. Solve for $x$ and $y$. $CE/EB=y/(1-y)$.

Comment: Is M the midpoint of AB? If you'd just like a hint, consider reading [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4063821/21813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hint: Use the fact that in equilateral triangle we have:

$FH+FG+FM=CM=h$

Show that : $FG=\frac 38 h$

Now use: $FG^2+CG^2=FC^2=(\frac34 h)^2$

which gives CG in terms of h. Similarly find GB in terms of f h. The ratio $\frac{CE}{EB}\approx \frac{CG}{GB}\approx \frac 32$.

Update: Another thing that helps you is using civa's theorem :

$\frac{AM}{MB}\cdot\frac{BE}{EC}\cdot\frac{CH}{HA}=1$

Comment: Hello from measuring your solution seems correct. But when I measure FH+FG+FM=CM=h it doesn't work. Is this based on the approximation? Or is this actually true? I can't prove it to myself.
Also, shouldn't than CG = HF?

Comment: This is a theorem that the sum is equal to altitude of triangle and it is only for equilateral triangle.

Comment: moreover, it's prove is simple. the sum of three triangles FAC, FAB and FBC is the area of ABC, Since  AB=AC=BC then you get FH+FG+FM=CM=h.